# A loop counting the number of lines that contain a string in a colum if a criteria is met (same ID)

Tags: r, for-loop

R beginner here.
My data looks like this: Each **ID** is recorded each day (**Date**) that the test subject is in the study. Also, the **Group** the test subject is in gets recorded. The test subject can be in group M or in any other group (K or 1-10).
I would like to have as output the count (**daysinM**) for each date the number of days the test subject was in group M. So if the test subject was in M 15 times and today is in group 7 the count would still be 15 until another day is spent in M.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
ID <- c(2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,7)
Date <- c("2020-1-1", "2020-1-2", "2020-1-3", "2020-1-4", "2020-1-5", 
          "2020-2-1", "2020-2-2", "2020-2-3", "2020-2-4", 
          "2020-1-1", "2020-1-2", "2020-1-3", "2020-1-4", "2020-1-5", "2020-1-6")
Date <- as.Date(Date)
Group <- c("2", "M", "M", "K", "M", "M", "M", "7", "M", "K", "M", "M", "M", "3", "M")
daysinM <- c(0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
Data = data.frame(ID, Date, Group, Count)
```

I know I need a loop but I can't figure it out. Here's what I tried:

```
Data$daysinM=0
 
for (i in 1:(nrow())){
  if (Data$Group == "M" && (Data[i+1,which(colnames(Data)=="ID")]==Data[i,which(colnames(Data)=="ID")])) 
    daysinM=daysinM+1
    Data[i,ncol(Data)+1]<-daysinM  
  }
}
```

Please use idiot-proof language.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the future, tag your questions with a language. That will help attract the right people to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested, you can use `tidyverse` (in this case, just the `dplyr` package), and try something like this.

The `%>%` will "pipe" results from one line to the next. Starting with your `Data`, you can use `group_by` so that subsequent operations are completed for each group (in this case, for each `ID`).

Then, `mutate` allows you to change or create a column in your data. We create a new column `daysinM` that is equal to the cumulative sum of where `Group` is "M".

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(daysinM = cumsum(Group == "M"))
```

In base R (without any additional packages), you could do:

```
Data$daysinM <- ave(Data$Group == "M", Data$ID, FUN = cumsum)
```

In this case, you can use `ave` to create smaller vectors based on group (in this case, `ID`). For each of these smaller vectors, we do the cumulative sum again where the `Group` is "M".

**Output**

```
      ID Date       Group daysinM
   <dbl> <date>     <chr>   <int>
 1     2 2020-01-01 2           0
 2     2 2020-01-02 M           1
 3     2 2020-01-03 M           2
 4     2 2020-01-04 K           2
 5     2 2020-01-05 M           3
 6     5 2020-02-01 M           1
 7     5 2020-02-02 M           2
 8     5 2020-02-03 7           2
 9     5 2020-02-04 M           3
10     7 2020-01-01 K           0
11     7 2020-01-02 M           1
12     7 2020-01-03 M           2
13     7 2020-01-04 M           3
14     7 2020-01-05 3           3
15     7 2020-01-06 M           4
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, daysinM :=  cumsum(Group == "M"), ID]
```